# Conditional Sequence repeat In R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix made of a very long series of integers bounded  between 1 and 6. I  would like to create an output matrix of the same length than the original matrix and 6 columns (the maximum value in the original matrix) where 1 is repeated  n time the value of the first encountered integer in the column of the integer value. (i.e if the first value is 6 it would repeat 1 x 6 times in the 6th column of the output matrix and then the value in in row 7 of the original matrix would be used for the next repeat sequence. I have shown an example in the below. Is there an efficient way to do this in R?

```
Original Matrix         output  Matrix                      
    c1          c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6
R1  1       R1  1   0   0   0   0   0
R2  1       R2  1   0   0   0   0   0
R3  3       R3  0   0   1   0   0   0
R4  2       R4  0   0   1   0   0   0
R5  6       R5  0   0   1   0   0   0
R6  1       R6  1   0   0   0   0   0
R7  1       R7  1   0   0   0   0   0
R8  1       R8  1   0   0   0   0   0
R9  1       R9  1   0   0   0   0   0
R10 4       R10 0   0   0   1   0   0
R11 4       R11 0   0   0   1   0   0
R12 2       R12 0   0   0   1   0   0
R13 1       R13 0   0   0   1   0   0
R14 3       R14 0   0   1   0   0   0
R15 1       R15 0   0   1   0   0   0
```

A further example of the input and output matrix to make my above example clearer.

```
Input matrix            Output matrix                                                           
    c1          1   2   3   4   5   6
1   2       1   0   1   0   0   0   0
2   2       2   0   1   0   0   0   0
3   1       3   1   0   0   0   0   0
4   6       4   0   0   0   0   0   1
5   3       5   0   0   0   0   0   1
6   4       6   0   0   0   0   0   1
7   5       7   0   0   0   0   0   1
8   4       8   0   0   0   0   0   1
9   5       9   0   0   0   0   0   1
10  4       10  0   0   0   1   0   0
11  3       11  0   0   0   1   0   0
12  3       12  0   0   0   1   0   0
13  2       13  0   0   0   1   0   0
14  3       14  0   0   1   0   0   0
15  4       15  0   0   1   0   0   0
16  5       16  0   0   1   0   0   0
17  5       17  0   0   0   0   1   0
18  5       18  0   0   0   0   1   0
```

Comment: I have edited the second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simplistic solution but it works:

```
input_data <- c(1, 1, 3, 2, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1)
result <- matrix(0, nrow = length(input_data), ncol = 6)

counter <- 0
for (i in 1:length(input_data)){
  if (counter == 0){
      counter <- set_value <- input_data[i]              
  }

  result[i, set_value]  <- 1
  counter <- counter - 1

}

> cbind(input_data, result)

 [1,]          1 1 0 0 0 0 0
 [2,]          1 1 0 0 0 0 0
 [3,]          3 0 0 1 0 0 0
 [4,]          2 0 0 1 0 0 0
 [5,]          6 0 0 1 0 0 0
 [6,]          1 1 0 0 0 0 0
 [7,]          1 1 0 0 0 0 0
 [8,]          1 1 0 0 0 0 0
 [9,]          1 1 0 0 0 0 0
[10,]          4 0 0 0 1 0 0
[11,]          4 0 0 0 1 0 0
[12,]          2 0 0 0 1 0 0
[13,]          1 0 0 0 1 0 0
[14,]          3 0 0 1 0 0 0
[15,]          1 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

Comment: This is really great, exactely what I was after. Thank you so much fopr contributing the answer.

Comment: Glad to help ! :)